# Why do we need to define odbc connection to connect to sql server(but not always)

Tags: sql-server, odbc, cognos

When i open up sql server management studio and make a connection to an sql server database, it connects fine. But when i try to define a connection to the same sql server in cognos administration, andthen try to test the connection through the local framework manager, it says connection failed. And I need to define an odbc connection in my control panel for it to work.
So my question is..why sql server management studio does not need odbc connection, but cognos needs it? I have also heard that ms access needs it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of Data Source you're creating in Cognos Administration.  If you select ODBC as the data source type, it will attempt to use ODBC to connect.  You probably want to select the appropriate SQL Server data source type.